# Using Azure SQL for asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, azure

I've designed a website in Visual Studio and I'm starting on the database aspect of the site now. I'm using Azure to host the site at the moment and I was wondering is it best to create the database on Azure and then connect it to asp.net or design it in Visual Studio and then connect to Azure so I can store it there?
I also run the website locally a lot when I am testing it for design purposes so would building it in Azure affect this?
Im also using visual studio ultimate 2013 but its a pre release version and I can't use the azure sdk with it. Will it work on the full version of 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure SQL Database at its core is essentially compatible with standard SQL Server.  There is a published guide on what the limitations are (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336245.aspx) that you should understand first but I'd recommend that you work locally and then push your changes to Azure SQL Database.  Note that like any changes to schemas / databases in SQL Server you'll still need to manage those transitions appropriately as part of your deployment process.  HTH.